# custom checked listview

Tags: android

I am New to Android. My Requirement is to check an item of list view and i want show the selected items in next activity.

can anyone help me..

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) to work with listview

Then you can pass that value to you next activity by

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
           String s = ((TextView) view).getText().toString()  ;//get the string 
             Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
              i.putExtra("packageName.term", s; //attach you value 
              startActivity(i); //start activity  
    }
  });
```

from NextActivity you can read this by

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 String term = extras.getString("packageName.term"); //read that value
```

Answer (score 0):

see this example for listView with check-boxes:
http://www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/custom-listview-ability-check-items/

In order to "move" the selected items to the new activity, you can use the traditional way of transferring data between activities - see this: 
[In Android: How do I get variables/data from one screen to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347152/in-android-how-do-i-get-variables-data-from-one-screen-to-another)

or if you want to move a complex object, the most simple way would be to create a singleton object and use it as a "transporter".